# Wix customaction to delete folders with a wildcard

Tags: wix

I want to remove folders on an installation/uninstallation with WiX. My installer installs a user and I want to delete these user account folders since, by default, WiX deletes the user account and not the folder.

Every time our installer runs it creates a new folder `userName<MachineName><#>`. I want to clean out all folders starting with `userName`.

Comment: So, what is your question? Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1):

```
<RemoveFolder Id= "FolderID_of_Folder_to_Remove" On= "uninstall"/>
```

I use this element whenever a folder is created.  The parent is a component so whichever is the component that creates the folder is where I'd put this element, else you have to override the parent directory.

http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/removefolder.html